# How to configure ajax select2 for working with a barcode scanner

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have an ajax select2 (v 3.5.4) perfectly working but now I need it to work with a barcode scanner. 
I need to detect when enter key is pressed. The scanner inserts code into select2 input followed by an enter key.

The problem is the scanner is too fast and the ajax call does not get to finish before enter key is pressed.

This is my code so far:

```
$('#my_select').select2
    initSelection: (elm, callback) ->
      data =
        id: $(elm).data "record-id"
        name: $(elm).data "record-text"
      callback(data)
    ajax:
      url: url
      dataType: "jsonp"
      quietMillis: 100
      data: (term, page) ->
         query: term
         limit: 10
         page: page
      results: (data, page) ->
         more = (page * 10) < data.total

         results: data.records
         more: more
```

Comment: Add your Relevent code what you have done so far..!!!

Comment: @HareshVidja sorry, I've added my code to the question

Comment: Do you mean, enter is pressed in search textbox?

Comment: @dns_nx yes. Imagine search textbox has focus. Then if you scan the code 12345 the scanner enters '12345' and Enter key.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem and manage to fix it with the following patch. (It's against v4.0.2.)

```
--- a/select2.js    2018-03-09 08:33:38.000000000 +0700
+++ b/select2.js    2018-05-04 10:38:22.605348402 +0700
@@ -896,7 +896,7 @@
     var $loading = this.option(loading);
     $loading.className += ' loading-results';

-    this.$results.prepend($loading);
+    this.$results.html($loading);
   };

   Results.prototype.hideLoading = function () {
```

Comment: Confirmed to be working in Metronic 7.1.6, where select2 is integrated in plugins.bundle.js.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I needed to set a value after page reload. I think, my workaround could help you, too. But maybe someone knows a better way?

I initialized the `select2` box with the ajax result (in your example code '12345'):

```
var selectionList = [{ id: '12345', text: '12345' }];
$("#my_select").select2({
                                data: selectionList
                            });
```

Then I set the value and triggered the `change` event.

```
$("#my_select").val("12345").trigger("change");
```

After that, I initialized the `select2` box again with `ajax` loading. This is the code you posted above:

```
$('#my_select').select2
    initSelection: (elm, callback) ->
      data =
        id: $(elm).data "record-id"
        name: $(elm).data "record-text"
      callback(data)
    ajax:
      url: url
      dataType: "jsonp"
      quietMillis: 100
      data: (term, page) ->
         query: term
         limit: 10
         page: page
      results: (data, page) ->
         more = (page * 10) < data.total

         results: data.records
         more: more
```

With this way, you have set your `ajax` value in the `select2` box.
I'm not 100% sure, if this is what you want to achieve. Or do you really need to fire the pressed enter key? Please let me know, if this solution helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, and solved by this code:

```
 $('#products').select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#add_modal"),
    theme: "bootstrap",
    placeholder: 'Select product',
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    ajax: {
        url: '/shop-all-products',
        delay: 500,
        data: function (params) {
            var query = {
                search: params.term
            }
            return query;
        }
    }
})
```

Hope it be helpful for you.